# Autogenerated form inputs using Semantic-UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, semantic-ui

I want to create a form to input usernames using Semantic-UI.
On my site user can have several names - so I want to create a form for user to modify his/her names.
I want to create something like this
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjdDC.png)
There is a list with one required field and a green iconed + button, attached to the right top corner of the input and a label "Name".
When user clicks on green plus a new input field is spawned with a red - button attached to its corner. Also "Name" changes to "Names".
When user clicks on red minus button, field, at which it was attached to, colapses.
The main questions are:
1. Which HTML layout should I choose?
2. How to implement the "input with a button, attached to corner"?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment,

I only wrote a very simple HTML layout (not include javascript)

[image]

I just added a button inside of the input container,

and made the button position absolute.

```
.ui.input .button
{
    position: absolute;
    top     : -15px;
    right   : -15px
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJXWqN

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for.